# Google Drive Spreadsheets: Combining IF and VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to work out a formula for combining an `IF` statement and a `VLOOPUP`.

Basically, I want the formula to return a value if a value was found through VLOOKUP, or to return something else if not found...

I have experimented with

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$2:$B$31, 1, 0),"FOUND","NOT FOUND!")
```

... but this doesn't seem to work.

Many thanks for any thoughts you might have...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

An old thread but would like to submit a cleaner solution for the Vlookup example or places where you want to use the value returned by a formula-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$2:$B$31, 1, 0),"NOT FOUND")
```

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to check whether A1 exists in B2:B31 then VLOOKUP isn't required. Either use `MATCH` like this

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,$B$2:$B$31,0)),"FOUND","NOT FOUND")`

or shorter with `COUNTIF`

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$31,A1),"FOUND","NOT FOUND")`

Answer (score 4):

`ISERROR()` can test to see if a formula generates an error or not.

In this case, `IF` and `VLOOKUP` can be combined using

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$2:$B$31, 1, 0)),"NOT FOUND!", "FOUND")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(
C2,IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!B2:B2000"),0)),"FOUND","NOT FOUND")
```

If the matching data is in another file we can use the above formula.